# как заставить TextToSpeech говорить на русском?

Tags: android, tts, android-text-to-speech

написал простенькую программу с TTS. пробую воспроизводить фразы на английском и на русском. на русские не раегирует, но английские произносит. Как заставить его говорить на русском?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего просто не установлен русский голос на девайсе в настройках синтеза речи.

Comment: что-то я не ублю где их менять

Comment: @nick_dnepr, Настройки-Язык и клавиатура-Преобразование текста в речь-Синтезатор речи (произвоитель, Google, например)-Установка голосовых данных-Русский

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать новую Locale:
`Locale locale = new Locale("RU");`

Затем в в методе onInit твоего TextToSpeach:

```
textToSpeach.setLanguage(locale);
```